# Weak reference between parent and child classes

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

Can we communicate between classes like below code instead of using delegate/protocol pattern and notification. I haven't seen any code example like this. But just curious to know why this should work or not work.

```
class Class1 {

    var class2Obj: Class2 = Class2()
    init() {
      class2Obj.class1Obj = self
    }

    func class1Method() {
       print("Parent")
    }
}

class Class2 {

   weak var class1Obj: Class1?

   func class2Method() {
      class1Obj.class1Method()
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can communicate like this. But the delegate, block and closure are more comprehensible for other people to understand that Class2 calls back  through the "method". It's a "what is the best practice” issue. :)

Comment: @YunCHEN - Yes, you can use the closure pattern, too. But I'd qualify the claim that it is "best practice" to use closures. Like most design choices, it's more complicated than this. It really depends. In simple cases, a closure can be useful. But in richer interfaces, the delegate-protocol pattern is often superior. It just depends upon the nature of the interface. But, I agree, that Anshu's pattern of two tightly-coupled classes is suboptimal.

Comment: @Rob, Agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

What you have here *is* a delegate pattern. Your delegate property is merely called `class1Obj` rather than the more customary `delegate` name. The key issue here is that you're not using a protocol, and as a result these two classes are "tightly coupled," i.e. `Class2` is highly dependent upon details of the `Class1` implementation. Furthermore, with these two tightly coupled classes, it's not immediately clear which methods of `Class1` that `Class2` might need. It makes maintenance of `Class1` harder because so it's easy to accidentally make a change that breaks behavior in `Class2`. It also makes it hard to use `Class2` in conjunction with some other class other than `Class1`.

Instead, you'd generally declare a protocol to precisely articulate the nature of the contract between `Class2` and other object that might need to use it. The result is that the classes are less tightly coupled, i.e. `Class2` needs to know nothing about the other class other than its conformance to the protocol in question. Furthermore, when editing `Class1`, if you declare it to conform the the protocol, the compiler will warn you when you fail to implement some required method or property.

So, with a negligible amount of work up-front, the protocol makes the code much easier to maintain. It also provides some additional flexibility whereby you may use `Class2` in conjunction with something other than `Class1` in the future.

Bottom line, protocols can result in code that is easier to maintain and is more flexible, with no hidden assumptions.

---

If you don't want to use the delegate-protocol pattern, another alternative is to use a closure, where `Class1` supplies a block of code that `Class2` can call. So you can do something like:

```
class Class1 {

    var class2Obj = Class2()

    init() {
        class2Obj.handler = { [weak self] in     // note `weak` reference which avoids strong reference cycle
            self?.class1Method()
        }
    }

    func class1Method() {
        print("Parent")
    }
}

class Class2 {

    var handler: (() -> Void)?

    func class2Method() {
        handler?()
    }

}
```

While the delegate-protocol pattern is useful when you have a rich interface between the two classes, this closure pattern when you have a very simple interface between the two classes.

Frankly, a more common permutation of the above is where the closure is more directly associated with some particular request that `Class1` initiates in `Class2`. So, you might just make the parameter a closure to the appropriate method in `Class2`. Furthermore, you're often passing data back, so imagine that we're passing back an optional `String`:

```
class Class1 {

    var class2Obj = Class2()

    func performClass2Method() {
        class2Obj.class2Method { string in
            guard let string = string else { return }

            self.class1Method()
        }
    }

    func class1Method() {
        print("Parent")
    }
}

class Class2 {

    func class2Method(completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        // do something which creates `string`

        // when done, call the closure, passing that `string` value back

        completionHandler(string)
    }

}
```

These closure patterns a great way to do simple interfaces between objects, but also keeps the two classes very loosely coupled (i.e. `Class2` has no dependencies upon `Class1`), much like using a protocol in the delegate pattern did. But hopefully the above closure examples illustrate a simple alternatives to the rich delegate-protocol pattern.